# Crop image by horizontal lines, but they are not always straight, using command line

Tags: command-line, image-processing

I have a lot of images looking like this
[image: book image]
[image: paper image]

Is there a way to follow the horizontal lines and make a new image from to top of the line to the bottom of the horizontal line and between the end of the image and next horizontal line? I have research using ImageMagick, but i didnt find anything that will work for me. This is a code that it is currently **not** working for me

```
./multicrop -f 10 -m save [Source] [Destination]
```